# Validating XML node structure with Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the file:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<AUTOSAR xmlns="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0 AUTOSAR_4-2-2_STRICT_COMPACT.xsd">
    <AR-PACKAGES>
        <AR-PACKAGE>
            <SHORT-NAME>RootP_Composition</SHORT-NAME>
            <COMPOSITION-SW-COMPONENT-TYPE>
                <SHORT-NAME>Compo_VSM</SHORT-NAME>
                <CONNECTORS>
                    <ASSEMBLY-SW-CONNECTOR>
                        <SHORT-NAME>PP_CS_VehicleSPeed_ASWC_M6_to_ASWC_M740</SHORT-NAME>
                        <PROVIDER-IREF>
                            <CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF DEST="SW-COMPONENT-PROTOTYPE">/RootP_Composition/Compo_VSM/Instance_ASWC_M6</CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF>
                            <TARGET-P-PORT-REF DEST="P-PORT-PROTOTYOPE">/RootP_ASWC_M6/ASWC_M6/PP_CS_VehicleSPeed</TARGET-P-PORT-REF>
                        </PROVIDER-IREF>
                        <REQUESTER-IREF>
                            <CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF DEST="SW-COMPONENT-PROTOTYPE">/RootP_Composition/Compo_VSM/Instance_ASWC_M740</CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF>
                            <TARGET-R-PORT-REF DEST="R-PORT-PROTOTYOPE">/RootP_ASWC_M740/ASWC_M740/RP_CS_VehicleSPeed</TARGET-R-PORT-REF>
                        </REQUESTER-IREF>
                    </ASSEMBLY-SW-CONNECTOR>
                </CONNECTORS>
            </COMPOSITION-SW-COMPONENT-TYPE>
        </AR-PACKAGE>
    </AR-PACKAGES>
</AUTOSAR>
```

I want to check for the `ASSEMBLY-SW-CONNECTOR` node if he has as child `SHORT-NAME`, `PROVIDER-IREF`, `REQUESTER-IREF` and if `PROVIDER-IREF/REQUESTER-IREF` has as child (grandchild for `ASSEMBLY-SW-CONNECTOR`) `CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF` and `TARGET-P-PORT-REF/CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF` and `TARGET-R-PORT-REF`

So far I have this code:

```
tree = ET.parse('C:\\test\Abu\TRS.ABU.GEN.002\output\Connectors.arxml')
root = tree.getroot()
child = ["SHORT-NAME", "PROVIDER-IREF", "REQUESTER-IREF"]
grandchild = ["CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF", "TARGET-P-PORT-REF", "CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF", "TARGET-R-PORT-REF"]
connector = '{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}ASSEMBLY-SW-CONNECTOR'
for element in root.iter(tag = connector):
    for child in element:
        for grandchild in child:
            if child.tag.split('}', 1)[1] in child:
                if grandchild.tag.split('}', 1)[1] in grandchild:
                    print("yes")
                else:
                    print("No")
```

Where am I wrong? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**

```html
tree = etree.parse('C:\\test\Abu\TRS.ABU.GEN.002\output\Connectors.arxml')
root = tree.getroot()
found_name = found_provider = found_requester = found_contextP = found_targetP = found_contextR =found_targetR = False
connectors =  root.findall(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}ASSEMBLY-SW-CONNECTOR>")
for elem in connectors:
    if elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}SHORT-NAME>"):
        found_name = True
    if elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}PROVIDER-IREF>"):
        found_provider = True
        for child in elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}PROVIDER-IREF>"):
            if child.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF>"):
                found_contextR = True
            if child.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}TARGET-P-PORT-REF>"):
                found_targetP = True
    if elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}REQUESTER-IREF>"):
        found_requester = True
        for child in elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}REQUESTER-IREF>"):
            if child.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF>"):
                found_contextR = True
            if child.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}TARGET-R-PORT-REF>"):
                found_targetR = True

if found_name and found_provider and found_requester and found_contextP and found_targetP and found_contextR and found_targetR:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Any idea why i get False result?

Comment: What is printed vs what you expect?

Comment: you can use a proper XML validator like rng.

Comment: @cricket_007 nothing is printed. I want to integrate this code into a function which returns True or False, but first, I want to make this code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

Firstly, a few typos/small mistakes:

- you have an unnecessary closing tag (`>`)in all your find paths, so they all need removing
- in your `found_provider` section, you set `found_contextR` when I think you mean `found_contextP` (**P**, not **R**)
- using

  ```
  if elem.find("<path>"):
  ```

  raises warning, you should instead use

  ```
  if elem.find("<path>") is not None:
  ```

Secondly, you have made a mistake with your `child` element sections, for example in the `found_provider` section:

```
if elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}PROVIDER-IREF>"):
    found_provider = True
    for child in elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}PROVIDER-IREF>"):
        if child.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF>"):
            found_contextR = True
        if child.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}TARGET-P-PORT-REF>"):
            found_targetP = True
```

You correctly find for the `PROVIDER-IREF` element, then you loop over its children trying to match the `CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF` and `TARGET-P-PORT-REF` elements. But you're doing this by searching for them as children of these child elements (ie grandchildren of `PROVIDER-IREF`), when they themselves *are* the children.

So either you need to be checking the tags of the child elements, rather than searching for elements under them:

```
if elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}PROVIDER-IREF") is not None:
    found_provider = True
    for child in elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}PROVIDER-IREF"):
        if child.tag == "{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF":
            found_contextP = True
        if child.tag == "{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}TARGET-P-PORT-REF":
            found_targetP = True
```

or you could try to extract the `PROVIDER-IREF` element and then find elements under it:

```
provider = elem.find(".//{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}PROVIDER-IREF")
if provider is not None:
    found_provider = True
    if provider.find("{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF") is not None:
        found_contextP = True
    if provider.find("{http://autosar.org/schema/r4.0}TARGET-P-PORT-REF") is not None:
        found_targetP = True
```

Obviously then do similarly for the `found_requester` section.

---

I think your initial approach was actually quite good; trying to specify a child-grandchild structure and then checking if this fits the XML. But you'd need to specify which grandchildren belong to which children, so maybe use nested dictionaries like this:

```
structure = {
    "ASSEMBLY-SW-CONNECTOR": {
        "SHORT-NAME": None,
        "PROVIDER-IREF": {
            "CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF": None,
            "TARGET-P-PORT-REF": None
            }
        "REQUESTER-IREF": {
            "CONTEXT-COMPONENT-REF": None,
            "TARGET-R-PORT-REF": None
            }
        }
    }
```

and then have a recursive function (ie, a function which calls itself) to search for the matching children until it reaches `None` and stops looking down that branch.

Comment: That's it! You got me out of the mess. Thanks a lot.